# Android: Multiple Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've done this before, with luck, so I can't understand why I'm messing it up now.

Quite simply, start a second activity from the main activity.

In my main Activity (Test.class):

```
Intent s = new Intent(Test.this, Settings.class);
this.startActivity(s);
```

My Settings Activity (Settings.class):

```
public class Settings extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    }
}
```

settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:text="Test"
    /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the application part of the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

This just crashes. No log entries, no nothing. Not even when I surround the creating and starting of the intent/activity with a try-catch with a debug tag.

I'm blind, or deaf, I know. But I really HATE these crashes where there are no errors anywhere.

I'm starting the intent inside the main Acitvity's onCreate() method, by the way.

Update: I also tried adding the second activity to the AndroidManifest.xml class like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Settings"></activity>
```

Comment: check your manifest boath activities are in same name test change 1 to settings

Comment: Is two LAUNCHER allowed? I thought Launcher is supposed to be only one, the one that starts when user clicks it? Furthermore, both android:name is the same. Change it.

Comment: @MrYanDao it doesnt matter you can have two launchers if you want to get to a spesific activity on icon click that doesnt make a crash

Comment: The identical names was a typo. They're not identical :-)

Comment: Disable any filtering in logcat and you should see error message with stacktrace, it has to be there

Comment: ready the stacktrace. it's all there. search the message that says "You must supply a layout_width attribute." It pretty much says it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things you need to fix.

**First**, your layout:

You need to define width and height to your `TextView` as below:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:text="Test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**Second**, you need to fix your `AndroidManifest.xml`. You are not properly defining both of your activities. See below:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

<!-- Test activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<!-- Settings activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Settings"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Argh. Made some typos there. Yup, that works. (The bad textview was only a quick test, hence the lacking definitions.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Settings"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it makes no difference.

Comment: dont do any intent in oncreate since onResume of that class needs to be executed but you're redirecting it even before tat. Best do it in a button click

Comment: I've discovered another solution too. if you wanna call the intent on `onCreate()` method then use `finsh()`, before you call `starActivity(intent);`

Comment: Good point. Starting it fromt he onCreate() method was just for testing - after I got it to work, I'm calling it from a listener.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your Settings Activity in manifest file, **without** specifying *category.LAUNCHER* for it.
It should look like this:

```
<activity android:name=".Settings"/>
```

Regarding "No log entries" - it seems like you are looking into logs of your app (filtered by your app TAG). You can disable any log filtering and should see error message and stacktrace of this crash in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

two launcher activity in AndroidManifest.xml ? , 2 same class Name ? here its wrong here

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

its use like
and make sure your class name

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.frank.test.Test"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <activity  android:name=".com.frank.test.Settings"></activity>
```

Comment: Yah, there were several mistakes AND typos - thanks for the help :-)